# iPad Bookmark Icons on a Cake PHP Site

Tags: ios, cakephp

How can I setup an iPad/iPhone bookmark icon on a cakephp site? I am using the correct filename - apple-touch-icon.png - and I have tried uploading it to /webroot and the directory above /webroot to no avail. I tried searching Google of course. Has anyone successfully done this? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sitting behind some sort of caching service like CloudFlare? That could potentially be delaying it.

Comment: No, not that I know of, but thank you for the tip.

Comment: Can you access them in your browser (by navigating to example.com/apple-touch-icon.png)?

Comment: Putting `<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png" />` into your layout `.ctp` file could help force it to find the icon.

Answer (score 1):

SharkofMirkwood's answer worked perfectly.

I added:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="../img/apple-touch-icon.png" />
```

to view/layouts/default.ctp

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to add multiple sizes like this:

```
echo $this->Html->meta(array(
  'rel' => 'apple-touch-icon-precomposed',
  'link' => '/img/apple-touch-icon-57x57-precomposed.png',
));
echo $this->Html->meta(array(
  'rel' => 'apple-touch-icon-precomposed',
  'sizes' => '72x72',
  'link' => '/img/apple-touch-icon-72x72-precomposed.png',
));
echo $this->Html->meta(array(
  'rel' => 'apple-touch-icon-precomposed',
  'sizes' => '114x114',
  'link' => '/img/apple-touch-icon-114x114-precomposed.png',
));
echo $this->Html->meta(array(
  'rel' => 'apple-touch-icon-precomposed',
  'sizes' => '144x144',
  'link' => '/img/apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png',
));
```

Comment: You are totally right! I like to add a nice article I read when I was adding touch icons to my page: http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/touch-icons

Comment: Indeed a very useful article